# PHP & PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have developed a website for personal use which may send mail. 
but the problem is when i ran it on local it works perfectly,
but when i ran it on domain it doesn't send mail & response is 
" Your Message is not submitted. "
Here's my code

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['sendmail']))

          {
            require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();                                   // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'example.sender@gmail.com';          // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '12345abcde'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                         // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                 // TCP port to connect to

   $mail->setFrom('example.sender@gmail.com');
    $mail->addAddress('example.reciver@gmail.com');   // Add a recipient

    $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject   = "Mail From Web";
 $mail->Body      = "
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th><p>Name: $f_name $l_name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Email Address </label></td>
    <td>: $email </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Phone Number </label></td>
    <td>: $phone </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Country </label></td>
    <td>: $country </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>State      </label></td>
    <td>: $state </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Message</label></td>
    <td>: $msg </td></tr>
</table>";

    $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

    if(!$mail->send())
    {
        echo    $_SESSION['mesg']="<span style='color:red;'>Your Message is not submitted.</span>";
        $_SESSION['actionMessage'] = $_SESSION['mesg'];
    }
 else 
{
echo
    $_SESSION['mesg']="<span style='color:green;'>Your Message is submitted.</span>";   
        $_SESSION['actionMessage'] = $_SESSION['mesg'];
}
  }
?>
```

Could any one please let me know why is this happens..?

Comment: Take the `$mail->send()` out of the if and just let it fail to see if you get more information on the reason for failure. You may also turn on debug in phpMailer which will give you more details too.

Comment: Maybe your hoster blocks specific ports.

Comment: Use the latest version of PHPMailer, and read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). It's probably that your ISP blocks outbound SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

in order to get more information try this to enable the exceptions and Debug. You can see what's happening in $mail->ErrorInfo;

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['sendmail'])) {
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'example.sender@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '12345abcde'; // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 587; // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('example.sender@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress('example.reciver@gmail.com'); // Add a recipient

        $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = "Mail From Web";
        $mail->Body    = "
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th><p>Name: $f_name $l_name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Email Address </label></td>
    <td>: $email </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Phone Number </label></td>
    <td>: $phone </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Country </label></td>
    <td>: $country </td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>State      </label></td>
    <td>: $state </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><label>Message</label></td>
    <td>: $msg </td></tr>
</table>";

        $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

            echo $_SESSION['mesg'] = "<span style='color:red;'>Your Message is not submitted.</span>";
            $_SESSION['actionMessage'] = $_SESSION['mesg'];
        } else {
            echo $_SESSION['mesg'] = "<span style='color:green;'>Your Message is submitted.</span>";
            $_SESSION['actionMessage'] = $_SESSION['mesg'];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
?>
```